# Tensorflow - fixed convolutional kernel

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I am trying to create a fixed convolutional kernel that applies a blur filter to each channel separately:

```py
# inputs = <previous layer>
kernel_weights = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                           [2, 4, 2],
                           [1, 2, 1]])
kernel_weights = kernel_weights / np.sum(kernel_weights)
kernel_weights = np.reshape(kernel_weights, (*kernel_weights.shape, 1, 1))
kernel_weights = np.tile(kernel_weights, (1, 1, inputs.get_shape().as_list()[3], 1))
return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d_native(max_pool, kernel_weights, strides=(1, 2, 2, 1), padding="SAME")
```

I'm currently under the impression that this convolutional kernel can/will change during training - how can I prevent it from doing so?
Would it be sufficient to wrap it in a tf.constant before passing it to the conv2d layer? Like so:

```py
kernel_weights = tf.constant(kernel_weights)
```

Thanks!

Comment: That should be sufficient, yes, and it's probably unneccessary since you're not passing variables for the kernel (IIRC TF implicitly converts constant-valued arrays passed to tensor inputs to tf.constant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [GPhilo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324713/tensorflow-fixed-convolutional-kernel?noredirect=1#comment101139570_57324713) correctly identifies: just passing the kernel as a tf.constant (or plain numpy array) works, verified by plotting the histogram for the kernel in tensorboard.